# Easiest Way to Compare 2 Xcode Projects Using Git

Tags: xcode, git

At some point in time my project was perfectly working and commit was made. After several days a change happened and suddenly it stopped to work.
How can I use git to compare the changes between to commits?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `git bisect`: https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/beginners-guide-git-bisect-process-elimination

Comment: Basically, you can sift through your history and narrow it down to the exact commit which introduced the bug.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do `git log` and find the approximate date you think the project was working fine.
2. Find the SHA of the commits around that date and find their diff by doing:

   ```
   git diff <SHA of commit1> <SHA of commit2>
   ```
3. To compare the changes in a specific `filename` do:

   ```
   git diff <SHA of commit1> <SHA of commit2> /path/to/filename/in/repo
   ```